# Applying XML shape for border as views background changes the previous color of a view in Android

Tags: android, colors, border, background-color, shapes

Trying to apply border to highlight the selected view with the help of this line:

```
findViewById(id_of_the_view_that_was_clicked)
.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageborder));
```

But the problem is when this shape is applied as background, the view's color gets changed to a new color. I want the solid color to remain the same as previous background color (before applying border), just the border should be applied. I also applied transparent color in XML, but on applying it becomes white (removes the previous color, say red to white). After applying the border, I also want to remove the border from view without changing the previous color background of the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#0000ff" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I had tried your xml code it's working fine suppose your colour code is different from same as previous background color.
or i can say u should focus on color.
if issue is different from my understanding let me know.

Comment: thanks for asking, it is resolved now actually I was selecting a view and trying to show border on the selected view by switch case taking view.getId() of the selected view to apply border, what I did was save hex color of background in some variable just before applying border and apply that color as solid color stroke and it seems that background is not changed the program was kind of big to post here, I will describe the solution here after some time thanks